# My Form isn't working with my Javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know if the problem is with my form or my javascript but the validation isn't working and I'm not getting any errors in the console. Can anyone check and see the form is working or the problem is with the javascript

```js
const formSection = document.getElementById('davididhere');
const mailInput = document.getElementById('email');
const messageError = document.getElementById('error-messages');

formSection.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  if (mailInput.value === mailInput.value.toLowerCase()) {
    messageError.textContent = '';
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    messageError.textContent = '*email must be in lower case <br> * form not sent';
  }
})
```

```html
<section id="contactpage" class="form-section">
  <div class="form-container">

    <form action="https://formspree.io/f/myyvzkag" method="post" id="davididhere">
      <ul class="form-info">
        <li>
          <input type="text" maxlength="30" name="user_name" class="name-text-box" id="full-name" placeholder="Full Name" required="" />
        </li>

        <li>
          <input type="email" name="user_email" class="name-last-text-box" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required="" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <textarea id="text-box" name="message" maxlength="500" class="enter-form" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Enter text here" required=""></textarea>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <input type="submit" value="Get in touch" class="send-btn" />
      <small id="error-messages"></small>
    </form>
```

my css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .greet {
    background: url(desktop2.svg) no-repeat 100% 0%;
  }


  .grid-containers {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }

  .picture-box {
    background: url(planeleft.svg) no-repeat 0% 20%,
      url(planeright.svg) no-repeat 100% 100%;
  }


  .send-btn {
    display: none;
  }

the .send-btn is the problem when it doesn't display in the desktop version it stops working with my function. So I need to figure out how to use media queries to work both breakpoints.
```

Comment: It's working in the snippet here. If I enter `FOOBAR@example.com` it shows the error. If I enter `foobar@example.com` it submits.

Comment: ahh thanks bro!! i dont know why its not working on the local

Comment: Are you sure the code is running? If you set a breakpoint in it, or add `console.log()` statements, do you get the expected result?

Comment: if i make a new page without styles it works but on my normal site it doesnt

Comment: Are you using a library like bootstrap for the styling? It may be interfering. Without more details, it's impossible to say what you need to do.

Comment: But if you just mean CSS, I don't see how that could cause a problem.

Comment: actually the form doesnt work properly with all the normal code

Comment: im only using normal css ...

Comment: Unless you can provide code that reproduces the problem, or a link to the site that fails, we can't help you.

Comment: if anyone is curious it works in the mobile version i but becasue of the media queries it doesnt work past the 768 breakpoint

Comment: Update the question with your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Code snipped is working here. Now the question is do you expect some kind of an error in the console since you stated that you are not receiving anything there. You can `throw` an error in addition to already defined `textContent`.

```
const formSection = document.getElementById('davididhere');
const mailInput = document.getElementById('email');
const messageError = document.getElementById('error-messages');

formSection.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  if (mailInput.value === mailInput.value.toLowerCase()) {
    messageError.textContent = '';
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    messageError.textContent = '*email must be in lower case <br> * form not sent';
    throw new Error('Email must be in lower case!');
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't think he's expecting something on the console. He's telling us that to indicate that the code isn't failing due to getting an error. The first thing we usually ask when someone is having a JS problem is "Are you seeing any errors in the console".

Comment: Code like this should not normally throw an exception, they report the error using the `messageError` div.